# Cosmos DB - Partition key for fixed collections

Tags: nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Can someone advise how to create **Fixed** collection (throughput - 400 RU) with logical partition keys? Is it possible?
It is necessary for me in order to migrate easily to unlimited collection in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot migrate from a fixed collection to a partitioned collection without physically copying your data over.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thanks. What about possibility to create fixed collection with logical partition keys? Since from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017040/purpose-of-a-partition-key-for-a-cosmos-db-fixed-10gb-collection I think so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a fixed collection with a partition key.

Also once a collection is created without a partition key, it cannot be converted to a partitioned one without being migrated form one collection to another.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the following sentence: "When you create a "fixed" 10 GB partition, there is only one physical partition allocated, whether you provide a partition key or not. Note that providing a partition key in this case is optional.

In summary, you are well off providing a partition key while creating this "fixed" collection, even though all partition key values will be mapped to the single partition." mentioned within https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017040/purpose-of-a-partition-key-for-a-cosmos-db-fixed-10gb-collection

Comment: I now realize (thanks to your link) that your question is essentially a duplicate of the question you linked to.